# Finding a time between 2 different time ranges

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm struggling with getting the following query to work correctly:

```
select date, time, amt, tran_id
from trans
where amt > 0
      and   time between'23:00:00' and '23:59:59'
      or    time between '00:00:00' and '5:59:59'
```

I'm trying to find over-night transactions, however, the 'or' statement throws off my other 'and' statement and the query is returning records where amt = 0.

I'm sure this is simple, I just haven't had any luck in my research.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   where amt > 0
   and  (
            time between'23:00:00' and '23:59:59'
    or    time between '00:00:00' and '5:59:59'
            )
```

You need parentheses to contain the OR scope to be paired only with the other time range.

Note. If that time column has a precision finer than second using between will cause inaccuracies, I always recommend using >= along with < such as this

```
where amt > 0
   and  (
            time >= '23:00:00' 
    or    ( time >= '00:00:00' and time < '6:00:00' )'
            )
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Additional to adding parenthesis: assuming `time` has a datatype of `TIME` this can be simplified to

```
select date, time, amt, tran_id
from trans
where amt > 0
      and (time >= '23:00:00' or time <= '5:59:59')
```

or

```
where amt > 0
      and time not between '06:00:00' and '22:59:59'
```

Btw, a time literal should always be written  `TIME '23:00:00'`

Comment: It has a datatype of integer, my guess is because of the massive amounts of trans data, would make it quicker to query?

Comment: Before there was a `TIME`/`TIMESTAMP` datatype (decades ago) time was stored as `FLOAT` with a specific `FORMAT` to make it look like an actual time. When it's stored as an `INT` at your site it might due to historical reasons or to save a bit space (4 vs. 6 byte).